# how to achieve true loose coupling using Prism and Unity

Tags: wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism, loose-coupling

I have developed a WPF application using `Prism` and `Unity` frameworks and I have some concerns regarding the following whether I have implemented them correctly or not.

- **Abstract classes / Interfaces** - I have organized interfaces for all the layers in one assembly and then referenced it in the respective library for implementation. Now, the referenced library has access to all the non required interfaces of other layers. For e.g. the service layer has access to `UI` interfaces. Is this the proper implementation in terms of `clear separation` or should I split it into multiple assemblies.
- **View Model dependencies** - I used `EventAggregator` mostly to communicate between view models. In some cases, I am passing the instance of other view models directly in the constructor and resolving it using DI container. I want to omit the direct view model dependency by introducing the interface to achieve clear separation. How can I organize the interface for view models into a separate assembly in such a way that the other developers could understand.To avoid creating multiple UI projects, I created only one single assembly and logically separated them into folders.
- **Abstract Module Class** - Instead of specifying all the dependencies in `bootstrapper.cs` file, I factored them in respective module. Most of my class lib projects has references to Prism libraries. Thus, UI specific namespaces are added to non `UI` related projects. Is there any better approach to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Abstract classes / Interfaces

I'd go for exactly as many "interface-assemblies" as necessary, having too many of them hurts. Example: if you *need* to prevent layer 1 from potentially communicating with layer 3, put the layer 1-to-layer 2-interfaces in one assembly and those for layer 2-to-layer 3 in another one.

> View Model dependencies

Normally, you shouldn't need to pass view models around at all. Pass around the data (a.k.a. model), the view models themselves don't hold any data that's either unavailable elsewhere or valuable to anyone but the view bound to the view model.

> Abstract Module Class

Your *prism application* references *prism*... so what? As long as only the `IModule` implementations receive the `IUnityContainer` I wouldn't care at all. If someone needs to publish an event, he get's the `IEventAggregator`... That's an interface already, and you can inject a mock in your tests, so no need for further abstraction.

Comment: Thank you so much. If i may ask, Could you please help me understand a bit further on the following.

**Abstract Module Class** - Is it a good idea to implement a logic to show / hide view based on certain event for the respective UI modules. For e.g. if there's no connection, I want to hide all the modules and show an Error screen. Currently, I have a separate `ViewManager` which is unloading all the views at one place. I would like to shift this logic in each `UI` module, but i am skeptical of publishing so many notifications.

Comment: If it's an event that affects all modules, I'd react centrally to it. You can add a region to your shell that covers the whole shell and is normally empty. Until the connection is lost, then navigate this region to an error screen that hides the whole app. This way, you have to react to the connection loss only once and you're sure that the ui is disabled.